# Excel count number of cells in column with "an" until next cell is non"an"

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I would like to count the number of cells in column with "an", where the counting starts at a given row and counts go down to count the number of cells with "an" until a non-"an" cell is found?

For example

```
Column A
opp
an 
an 
an
an
opp
```

I would like to calculate how many cell with "an" until the next non an cell.
For this example answer will be 4.

Another example

```
Column B:
an 
an 
opp 
an 
an
an
```

The answer will be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perhaps try the formula:

```
=SUM(MATCH(0,IF(OFFSET(A1:A7,MATCH("an",A1:A7,0)-1,0)="an",1,0),0))-1
```

Entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Where A1:A7 is the range. Change it accordingly.

---

EDIT: To count from the bottom, maybe this:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(C1:C9,MATCH(2,IF(OFFSET(C1,0,0,MATCH(2,IF(C1:C9<>"an",NA(),1)))="an",NA(),1)),0),"an")
```

Also entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. It works!!
But do you have any idea if it possible to count from bottom to top?

Comment: Do you have any idea if it possible to count from bottom to top?

Comment: @user2828608 How about the formula I just added to my answer?

Comment: Hi Jerry thanks again and I have another problem.

I have these in C2:C10
opp
an
an
an
an
opp
an
an
opp

and i used the formula =COUNTIF(OFFSET(C2:C9,MATCH(2,IF(C2:C9="in",NA(),1)),0),"in") and i get 5.. It suppose to be 2..
Can you figure out what is my problem? What is the '2' in the Match function means?
Appreciate ur reply. Thanks.

Comment: @user2828608 Hmm, are you sure that you get 5? I'm getting 0 ^^ But that's an interesting problem to which I don't have an answer right now. I effectively didn't consider the possibility of having something not "an" at the end, which will make things quite difficult. I'll let you know if I find something!

Comment: @user2828608 Btw, the `2` is just a number larger than 1 which I'm using in the IF function. `MATCH(#, RANGE)` returns the position of the last match if the default match type is picked, and thus, it will return the position of the last `1` in the array.